# Debug Soap UI tool calls

Tags: debugging, user-interface, soap

We are planning to use SOAP UI Pro to test our Services (developed in c#.net)
I am getting an error in the service and would like to debug the service call.
I am not able to attach a breakpoint.
Does anyone have tried to debug SOAP UI test tool call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got it working by attaching aspnetwp process!

Comment: Well done for posting this as an answer. Will be here for the next person.